# Oracle BGP IP address for Fastconnect Private Peering

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

How should I specify the Oracle BGP IP Address for FastConnect Private Peering? The documentation just says "The BGP peering IP address you want to use for the DRG, with either a /30 or /31 subnet mask." Should it be part of the VCN to which the DRG is assigned? Or it could be anything else I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always recommend that the BGP peering IPs should be unique in your network and certainly should not be within the range of the VCN you want to attach to your DRG, or indeed any VCN that you might want to reach through the DRG via [Transit Routing](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/transitrouting.htm).

Hope that helps,

Ben